# How can I get my tkinter prototype system calculate the correct total price

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkinter-button

I am a beginner, I am creating a prototype system for a DIY Store as part of my assignment, with Tkinter. The application works by filling out a simple survey to create an order. At the bottom of the page after you click that button 'Enter Data', your result of selections should appear including your total price.

I need some advice on how to write the calculation part of my system, which starts from def total(): within the code but the calculation part comes at total_length, which is where I am getting an error for 'not defining it' the error message(https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5lZg.png).

I don't know how to get passed that. I thought it was defined by my calculation of total_length = wallpaper_length_cost * 0.5.

```
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import filedialog
    from tkinter import ttk
    
    def display_wallpaper_prints():
        window = tk.Toplevel()
        window.title("View Wallpaper prints")
        window.geometry("400x400")
        image_path = "Picture1A.png"
        img = tk.PhotoImage(file=image_path)
        label = ttk.Label(window, image=img)
        label.image = img
        label.pack(side="top", pady=10)
    
    
    def enter_data():
    
    
        full_name = "Name: " + first_name_field.get() + "  " + surname_field.get()
        name_label.config(text=full_name)
        name_label.grid(column=0, row=4, columnspan=2)
        employeeID = "Employee ID: " + employeeID_field.get()
        ID_label.config(text=employeeID)
        ID_label.grid(column=6, row=4, columnspan=2)
        wallpaper_length = "Wallpaper length: " + wallpaper_length_combobox.get()
        wl_label.config(text=wallpaper_length)
        wl_label.grid(column=0, row=5, columnspan=2)
        wallpaper_selection = "Wallpaper selection: " + wallpaper_selection_combobox.get()
        ws_label.config(text=wallpaper_selection)
        ws_label.grid(column=6, row=5, columnspan=2)
        wallpaper_paste = "Wallpaper paste: " + wallpaper_paste_selection_combobox.get()
        wp_label.config(text=wallpaper_paste)
        wp_label.grid(column=0, row=6, columnspan=2)
        extras = "Extras: " + extras_selection_combobox.get()
        extras_label.config(text=extras)
        extras_label.grid(column=6, row=6, columnspan=2)
        lining_paper = "Lining: " + lining_paper_selection_combobox.get()
        lining_paper_label.config(text=lining_paper)
        lining_paper_label.grid(column=0, row=7, columnspan=2)
    
        print(full_name, employeeID)
        print(wallpaper_length, wallpaper_selection)
        print(extras, wallpaper_paste, lining_paper)
    
    
    def total_cost():
    
        wallpaper_per_metre_cost = 0
        if wallpaper_selection_combobox.get() == "Option A (30p per metre)":
            wallpaper_per_metre_cost = 0.30
        elif wallpaper_selection_combobox.get() == "Option B (60p per metre)":
            wallpaper_per_metre_cost = 0.60
    
    
        wallpaper_length_cost = 0
        if wallpaper_length_combobox.get() == "10 metres":
            wallpaper_length_cost = 10
        elif wallpaper_length_combobox.get() == "15 metres":
            wallpaper_length_cost = 15
        elif wallpaper_length_combobox.get() == "20 metres":
            wallpaper_length_cost = 20
        elif wallpaper_length_combobox.get() == "25 metres":
            wallpaper_length_cost = 25
    
        extras_per_metre_cost = 0
        if extras_selection_combobox == "Foil (12p per metre)":
            extras_per_metre_cost = 0.12
        elif extras_selection_combobox == "Glitter (18p per metre)":
            extras_per_metre_cost = 0.18
        elif extras_selection_combobox == "Embossing (6p per metre)":
            extras_per_metre_cost = 0.06
    
        lining_paper_cost = 0
        if lining_paper_selection_combobox == "Yes, £7.63 per roll":
            lining_paper_cost = 7.63
        elif lining_paper_selection_combobox == "No":
            lining_paper_cost = 0
    
        wallpaper_paste_cost = 0
        if wallpaper_paste_selection_combobox == "Yes, £13.99 per tub":
            wallpaper_paste_cost = 13.99
        elif wallpaper_paste_selection_combobox == "No":
            wallpaper_paste_cost = 0
    
        total_length = wallpaper_length_cost.get() * 0.5
    
        wallpaper_total = wallpaper_per_metre_cost * total_length
        extras_total = extras_per_metre_cost * wallpaper_length_cost
        total_cost = wallpaper_total + extras_total + wallpaper_paste_cost + lining_paper_cost
        total_price = "Total price: £" + total_cost.get()
        total_price_label.config(text=total_price)
        total_price_label.grid(column=0, row=10, columnspan=2)
    
        print(total_length)
        print(wallpaper_total)
        print(extras_total)
        print(total_price)
    
    
    
    
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.title("Wallpapering with Sally")
    
    frame = tk.Frame(window)
    frame.pack()
    
    #Customer info details
    customer_info_frame = tk.LabelFrame(frame, text="Customer details")
    customer_info_frame.grid(row= 0, column= 0, padx= 30, pady= 30)
    
    first_name_label = tk.Label(customer_info_frame, text= "First Name")
    first_name_label.grid(row= 0, column= 0)
    surname_label = tk.Label(customer_info_frame, text= "Surname")
    surname_label.grid(row= 0, column= 2)
    
    first_name_field = tk.Entry(customer_info_frame)
    surname_field = tk.Entry(customer_info_frame)
    first_name_field.grid(row= 0, column= 1)
    surname_field.grid(row= 0, column= 3)
    
    employeeID_label = tk.Label(customer_info_frame, text= "Employee ID")
    employeeID_label.grid(row= 1, column= 0)
    employeeID_field = tk.Entry(customer_info_frame)
    employeeID_field.grid(row= 1, column= 1)
    
    for widget in customer_info_frame.winfo_children():
        widget.grid_configure(padx=30, pady= 30)
    
    #Wallpaper form
    wallpaper_frame = tk.LabelFrame(frame)
    wallpaper_frame.grid(row=2, column=0)
    
    #Wallpaper Legnth
    wallpaper_length_label = tk.Label(wallpaper_frame, text= "How many metres of wallpaper would you like?")
    wallpaper_length_combobox = ttk.Combobox(wallpaper_frame, values=["10 metres","15 metres","20 metres","25 metres"])
    wallpaper_length_label.grid (row= 1, column= 0, pady= 10)
    wallpaper_length_combobox.grid (row= 2, column= 0)
    
    
    #Wallpaper Selection
    wallpaper_selection_label = tk.Label(wallpaper_frame, text= "Which wallpaper would you like?")
    wallpaper_selection_combobox = ttk.Combobox(wallpaper_frame, values=["Option A (30p per metre)","Option B (60p per metre)"])
    wallpaper_selection_label.grid(row= 3, column= 0, sticky= "news", padx= 15, pady= 10)
    wallpaper_selection_combobox.grid(row= 4, column= 0)
    
    #Select Extras
    extras_selection = tk.Label(wallpaper_frame, text= "Would you like any of the extras below?")
    extras_selection_combobox = ttk.Combobox(wallpaper_frame, values= ["Foil (12p per metre)", "Glitter (18p per metre)", "Embossing (6p per metre)"])
    extras_selection.grid(row= 5, column= 0, sticky= "news", padx= 15, pady= 10)
    extras_selection_combobox.grid(row= 6, column= 0)
    
    
    #lining paper combobox
    lining_paper_selection = tk.Label(wallpaper_frame, text= "Do you require Lining paper? (20m rolls for £7.63)")
    lining_paper_selection_combobox = ttk.Combobox(wallpaper_frame, values=["Yes, £7.63 per roll", "No"])
    lining_paper_selection.grid(row= 7, column= 0, sticky= "news", padx= 15, pady= 10)
    lining_paper_selection_combobox.grid(row= 8, column= 0)
    
    #wallpaper paste selection
    wallpaper_paste_selection = tk.Label(wallpaper_frame, text= "Do you require wallpaper paste? (10kg ready-mixed tubs)")
    wallpaper_paste_selection_combobox = ttk.Combobox(wallpaper_frame, values=["Yes, £13.99 per tub", "No"])
    wallpaper_paste_selection.grid(row= 9, column= 0, pady= 10, padx= 10)
    wallpaper_paste_selection_combobox.grid (row=10, column= 0)
    
    #enter data button
    enter_data_button = ttk.Button(frame, text= "Enter Data", command= enter_data)
    enter_data_button.grid(row= 3, column= 0, sticky= "news", padx= 20, pady= 20)
    
    #wallpaper_prints_button
    wallpaper_prints_button = ttk.Button(wallpaper_frame, text= "View wallpaper prints", command= display_wallpaper_prints)
    wallpaper_prints_button.grid(row= 3, column= 1, pady= 10)
    
    final_frame = tk.LabelFrame(frame)
    final_frame.grid(row=4, column=0)
    
    
    name_label = tk.Label(final_frame)
    
    ID_label = tk.Label(final_frame)
    wl_label = tk.Label(final_frame)
    ws_label = tk.Label(final_frame)
    wp_label = tk.Label(final_frame)
    extras_label = tk.Label(final_frame)
    lining_paper_label = tk.Label(final_frame)
    total_price_label = tk.Label(final_frame)
    
    
    
    
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why do you ask same question twice?

Comment: Why are you duplicate `def total_cost()` and variable is `total_cost()`?

Comment: line 86, in total_cost
    total_length = wallpaper_length_cost.get() * 0.5
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: It worked. The problem is you having duplicated again.